# Android: how to get ImageView to fill screen

Tags: android, layout

I don't know how to get an image to fill the screen, have tried everything, maybe there is some particular layout I should be using..?

I'm using an ImageView, however this just fills about 70% of the screen, leaving blank space at the bottom...

At the moment i'm just using a LinearLayout and setting its  background to my image. While this fills the screen, the image is slightly streched, which I don't want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

The code inside the ImageView tags of my layout file are:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

Comment: android:layout_height="match_parent" would do

Answer (score 56, accepted):

//in your xml Image attribute as

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or
//using thru programatically

```
imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

**Note:** this applies to when the image is set with android:src="..." rather than android:background="..." as backgrounds are set by default to stretch and fit to the View.

Comment: when you say use this through your coding also, do you mean in your Activity?

Comment: @Shaw no I mean that you can also do it thru program

Comment: This answer will stretch the image - I know it was not a requirement by the OP, but if you want an answer that fills the screen without ruining the aspect ratio, check @Revs answer below.

Answer (score 15):

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
```

just change layout width and height which would work with both 'center' and 'centercrop'

Comment: Not sure why this isn't accepted - This answer works without stretching the image and losing the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: it's perfect answer

Answer (score 5):

Use the below line in your Image `View` xml code.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: may be but it will fill the screen as OP want and if the image resolution is good enough then it should not give the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to remove

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

from the layoutparams, at the top of the xml of the activity. 
Otherwise the image will have problem filling the entire screen.

Answer (score -1):

You can use practically any layout and just set the background image to your image.  Then just make width and height fill parent.

or instance if you want just an image set it for your main linear layout

```
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/yourimage">
</LinearLayout>
```