# How to choose an image resolution to be shown fullscreen?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-resolution

I have an image which is actually 393 x 21 px, which I would like to set on the bottom of my View.

The problem is that, even if i set the width and the height to fill_parent, my image stays very small in the middle of the screen bottom and on the left and the right I have an empty field.

I can resolve this by reducing the Image width size mannualy but is ther any other solution whic could set the image in fullscreen ?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9230106/1012284

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my problem.  If you would like, you can give this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//in your xml Image attribute as

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or //using thru programatically

```
imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```