# Android background image

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a background image of size 720x1280 for larger screen phones like the LG Nitro P930. However, when I have an application that displays this image, it doesn't cover about half an inch at the bottom of the screen. The image looks fine on normal and small screen sizes, and I have included all of the support screens in my manifest file.

Is there something that I can do that will allow me to stretch the image to fit the screen, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: add android:scaleType="fitXY" http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478320/1012284

Comment: I think you should use `fill_parent` for height and width both in you layout xml.

Comment: I'm using background not an imageview. Should I switch?

Comment: Please don't use `fitXY` unless your background image has no details whatsoever. It will stretch it without regard to aspect ratio and will distort the image. Use `centerInside` or `centerCrop` instead, which will fit the image while maintaining aspect ratio (some cropping will occur).

Comment: My application consist of tabs, another thing I see is if I remove the background image and just change the color that half of inch is still black at the bottom. Any thoughs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was actually a setting on the phone that optimizes the application.

Answer (score 0):

add android:scaleType="fitXY" and fill_parent for height and width both in you layout xml

---

You don't have to use image view background should work fine, are you using a scroll view per chance somewhere?

Comment: No scroll view, I have fill_parent for width and height and I added the scaletype to the relativelayout background and still no luck.

Comment: Would you mind taking a screen shot of your 'Outline' for the layout?