# fit an image into the screen with out being distorted in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to fit an image of `900x150` into a screen of `1280x800` with out being distorted ..any help will be gr8 ..here is my `main.xml` file

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mypicture"
    android:src="@drawable/MyImage"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478320/1012284

Comment: Please describe exactly the result you want (a drawing would be perfect)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `fitCenter` instead of `centerCrop`

Comment: I tried both the 900 dimension is perfectly fitted with the screen but not the 150 dimenstion

Comment: What result do you want ? Fill both dimensions of the screeen (which will distort the image ratio) or keep image ratio and fill only one dimension ?

Comment: ..i want to keep image ratio and fit both dimensions if possible

Comment: That's not possible...screen ratio and image ratio are different... (screen ratio = 1280/800 = 1.6 and image ratio = 800 / 150 = 6)...

Comment: @xiongdi you mean you want to keep the scale ratio but fill the screen, so in this case, you have scroll vertically?

Comment: @Simon i think I should scale the image according to aspect ratio as suggested by @ Awais Tariq below

Answer (score 0):

You can scale up and down the image according to the aspect ratio. Or I see you have used scroll view simple your wrap content for image size which will show the picture completely without being distorted...

**EDIT**

```
private void scaleImage()
{
    // Get the ImageView and its bitmap
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_box);
    Drawable drawing = view.getDrawable();
    if (drawing == null) {
        return; // Checking for null & return, as suggested in comments
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();

    // Get current dimensions AND the desired bounding box
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int bounding = dpToPx(250);
    Log.i("Test", "original width = " + Integer.toString(width));
    Log.i("Test", "original height = " + Integer.toString(height));
    Log.i("Test", "bounding = " + Integer.toString(bounding));

    // Determine how much to scale: the dimension requiring less scaling is
    // closer to the its side. This way the image always stays inside your
    // bounding box AND either x/y axis touches it.  
    float xScale = ((float) bounding) / width;
    float yScale = ((float) bounding) / height;
    float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;
    Log.i("Test", "xScale = " + Float.toString(xScale));
    Log.i("Test", "yScale = " + Float.toString(yScale));
    Log.i("Test", "scale = " + Float.toString(scale));

    // Create a matrix for the scaling and add the scaling data
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

    // Create a new bitmap and convert it to a format understood by the ImageView 
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    width = scaledBitmap.getWidth(); // re-use
    height = scaledBitmap.getHeight(); // re-use
    BitmapDrawable result = new BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap);
    Log.i("Test", "scaled width = " + Integer.toString(width));
    Log.i("Test", "scaled height = " + Integer.toString(height));

    // Apply the scaled bitmap
    view.setImageDrawable(result);

    // Now change ImageView's dimensions to match the scaled image
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams(); 
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);

    Log.i("Test", "done");
}

private int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    float density = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float)dp * density);
}
```

Comment: if i remove the scroll view the image will be distorted ..i want to keep the aspect ratio but don't have a clue how

Comment: Thank you guys ..@Awais Tariq let me try it ;)

Comment: my image view is scaled but now it's so small instead of fitting the whole screen, i removed the scrollview from the main.xml ..any idea on the bounding

Comment: It's fill parent ..<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
 
 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 
 android:contentDescription="@string/mypicture"
 android:src="@drawable/MyImage"
     />
 
   
 </LinearLayout>  ..the scaled image is 250x42