# ImageView inside ScrollView won't resize to fill screen(keeping aspect)

Tags: android, layout, resize, imageview, scrollview

I'm having a very weird problem that I can't seem to be able to fix.

I can't seem to resize an Bitmap for an ImageView that is inside a ScrollView.
I tested the same Layout(but without the scroll) and the image is resized like it should be.

I found others having this kind of problem and for most using `android:fillViewport="true"` would suffice, but for me isn't working.

Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_app" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_white_background"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_app"
                android:contentDescription="@string/otl_img_description"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp" />            

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/full_image_view"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:alpha="0.3"
                android:background="@color/black_50"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onthelist_animal_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/full_image_view"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/onthelist_animal_date"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/otl_animal_name"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onthelist_animal_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/full_image_view"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/otl_animal_date"
                android:textColor="#a00000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/onthelist_share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/onthelist_animal_date"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/onthelist_animal_date"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/onthelist_animal_date"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/otl_animal_share"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />          

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/onthelist_save"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/custom_red_button"
            android:text="@string/otl_save"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp" /> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/onthelist_animal_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_white_background"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="@string/otl_animal_description"
            android:linksClickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and I'm setting the image for the ImageView `full_image_view` like this:

```
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    Log.i("OnTheList", "itemID[FI] = " + position);
    try {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(new ImageLoadTask().execute(
                JSONParserOnTheList.ANIMALS.get(position).photo).get());            
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_photo);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_photo);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The AsyncTask returns a Bitmap.

Thank you.

## EDIT (SOLUTION -> FIX)

After many things and methods applied trying to fix the issue I found the solution.
The idea was that the layout was working fine, the problem was that on some devices, because of the pixel density, the image was resize in a smaller version.

The fix that I applied was directly in the asynctask when I decoded the bitmap.

So the layout and everything else remained the same and the asyntask is this:

```
    private class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        loading.setTitle("Loading image ...");
        loading.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url;
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // Bitmap scale depending on density
            // For example: 
            // 1600*1200 image to be resized to 640*480
            // (1600*2 equal to 640*5)
            options.inDensity = 5;
            options.inTargetDensity = 2;
            options.inScaled = false;
            // Decode the bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
            input.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        loading.dismiss();
        loading.cancel();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Notice the options for `BitmapFactory` that is the important part that fixes the issue.

Also, to not have a very big image(a.k.a Full size image) you can give dimensions depending on the size of the screen like this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
imageView.setMaxHeight(screenSize()[0]-150);
imageView.setMaxWidth(screenSize()[1]-150);


private int[] screenSize() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    return new int[] {height, width};
```

Hope this helps anyone that struggles with this in the future.
    }

Comment: After some tests I found that this could be because I'm putting an bitmap inside of the ImageView ...
When I put the same image in the ImageView from the drawable's through XML layout it is resized ok.
Does anyone know how can I fix this ?
Thank you!

Comment: Another thing that I noticed is that everything is working well on some devices. From what I have here to test on, the results are like this:
It is working for: Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 and HTC Desire Bravo.
It is NOT working for: Samsung Galaxy S4.
What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 2):

Please add fadingEdge and fillViewport to scrollview

```
<ScrollView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:fadingEdge="none"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_app" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Please state the problem word by word, for the other part change all of the:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/full_image_view"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/onthelist_animal_date"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/onthelist_animal_date"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/onthelist_animal_date"
```

To:

```
android:layout_below="@id/full_image_view"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/onthelist_animal_date"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/onthelist_animal_date"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/onthelist_animal_date"
```

E.G. - Remove the "+", this is used only for "`android:id`" and marks the name of the layout.

Comment: The problem is that the image that is displayed is not resized how it should be(it is smaller, much more smaller), meaning I want it to be resized depending on the device screen size(but to also keep it's proportions).
The arrangement of the Items in the layout is not a problem, but the ImageView size!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9230106/3014036) is the real easy solution! 
use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your `ImageView`.